# How to proxy Vite's HMR request in Docker?

Tags: node.js, nginx, vite

I have a developer environment where there is an Nginx dev server and some requests are routed to my local machine and some a routed to the staging environment in the internet.

I'm using vitejs.dev and everything works except for the Websocket connection of Vite's Hot Module Replacement (HMR).

**vite.config.ts**

```
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    host: true,
    port: 3300,
    hmr: {
      path: '/__vite_hmr',
    },
  },
})
```

**nginx config**

```
location ~* /__vite_hmr {
    proxy_pass "http://cr-frontend:3300";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

I can successfully proxy other requests to `http://cr-frontend:3300` but not Vite's HMR. This is what I get:

```
client.ts:28 WebSocket connection to 'wss://url.xyz:3300/__vite_hmr' failed:
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Vite's documentation of the config options for the `server` and `server.hmr` properties is just shabby.

I've got rid of the same error you get with this config:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  server: {
    //https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/3396
    host: true,
    port: 8015, //default is 3000 but I have multiple apps within one site running so I need to define multiple custom ports on the same machine / container
    https: true,
    hmr:{
      clientPort: 9026,
    },
  }
})
```

Where `server.port` is the internal port of the node docker container and `server.hmr.clientPort` is the port the browser on my local machine is sending requests to (docker maps my machine's localhost:9026 to the node container's localhost:8015)

Comment: Any chance you could post your docker and compose files you have this working with?

Comment: @mildrenben
sure, only thing is, I didn't have opened this project for months and currently reorganizing my dev environment. But could upload it to github by coming Monday, if it's not too late for you

Comment: @FullStackAlex I would love to see this too! Mainly the nginx conf

Comment: @zabaat

The problem is I have a very complex development system for my own needs. I'm not sure if it's any of use for you if I publish some single files of it on github gist. Rather I would need to publish the whole git repo and write a documentation which is a pile of work. It contains local nginx server blocks (virtual hosts) proxying to docker nginx container. Then there are also separated mysql, php and node containers. Within the node container I have custom project setup. And then I have to clean up my project's (private) data. Too much work. Sorry.

Comment: @FullStackAlex
I was able to figure it out for mine actually. Thank you for your explanation and I totally understand

Comment: @zabaat Can you post your solution? I'm proxying resources, but can't get HMR in docker to work too.